# Returning list containing combinations of numbers in python using recursion only

Tags: recursion, append, combinations

This program prints out the different combinations of elements from the list. the idea is to either select the element or don't. The "print(store)" prints out the correct answers, however, if I try to make a list out of these answers it appears something is going wrong.

From what I understand from debugging, when "store.append(lst[i])" executes in the current function call at that instant "ans" is updated in the previous call. I am not sure how to go about returning a list of all the combinations.

```
ans = []

def comb(lst,i,store):
    if i ==len(lst):
       print(store)
       global ans
       ans.append(store)
    else:
       comb(lst,i+1,store) # dont select element
       store.append(lst[i])
       comb(lst,i+1,store) # select the element
       store.pop()

def driver(lst):
    comb(lst,0,[])
    return ans

print(driver([1,2,3]))



#OUTPUT:
[]
[3]
[2]
[2, 3]
[1]
[1, 3]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
# return ans output:
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```py
def comb(lst, i = 0, store = []):
    if i == len(lst):
        return [store]
    x = comb(lst, i + 1, store)
    y = comb(lst, i + 1, store + [lst[i]])
    return x + y
```

I prefer not appending to a global `ans` or popping the `store`. Also, as far as possible don't use mutation.